# Count no of session

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-image-services

I am using IBM Filenet for storing/retrieving documents on Server. I perform these operations for interacting with documents by using ISRA (Image services Resource Adapter) API. I want to count the no. of session created by one user on Filenet Server using ISRA API.

Answer (score 0):

Check **IBM FileNet Dashboard aka FileNet System Manager (aka P8SD)** which has counter for number of user sessions. (depends on your back end FileNet P8 or IS.